# How to change background color of Windows Phone Listpicker in FullScreen Mode

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, background, popup, listpicker

This question has been asked before but the answers provided have not worked for myself and others.  The style for the listpicker is provided by I haven't been able to get the background of the Listpicker to change color (in this case yellow) despite trying every property I can think of to get it to change.  What is wrong with the code?

---

```XAML
<Style TargetType="toolkit:ListPicker" x:Key="ListPickerStyle1">
    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>-->
    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="YellowGreen"/>-->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ListPicker">
                <StackPanel>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PickerStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"                                         Duration="0">                                             <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame                                             Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundColor}"                                             KeyTime="0"/>                                         </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames   Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"  Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  Value="Yellow" KeyTime="0"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames   Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"  Duration="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  Value="200" KeyTime="0"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentControl   Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"  
                                          Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
                                          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"  Margin="0 0 0 8"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <!--<Border   x:Name="Border"   Background="Yellow" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"  BorderThickness="2">-->
                        <Border   x:Name="Border"   Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"  BorderThickness="2">
                            <Canvas x:Name="ItemsPresenterHost" MinHeight="46">
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter">
                                    <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ItemsPresenter>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Border>
                        <Popup x:Name="FullModePopup">
                            <!--<Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">-->
                            <Border Background="Yellow" BorderThickness="200">
                                <!-- Popup.Child should always be a Border -->
                                <Grid Background="Yellow">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <ContentControl   Grid.Row="0" Content="{TemplateBinding FullModeHeader}" Background="Yellow" 
                                                          Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" 
                                                          FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"   
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="24 12 0 0"/>
                                    <ListBox  x:Name="FullModeSelector" Grid.Row="1"  ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ActualFullModeItemTemplate}" 
                                                  FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"  Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}" Background="Yellow">
                                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Background="Yellow"/>
                                                <!-- Ensures all containers will be available during the Loaded event -->
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    </ListBox>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Did you manage to get a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating an interface to represent `ListPickerPage`, and changing any code references in the Toolkit to use the interface (`IListPickerPage`) instead.

Then, I just created a new `PhoneApplicationPage`, and copied & slightly modified the source (`xaml & xaml.cs`), (I made it implement `IListPickerPage`)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Microsoft.Phone.Controls
{
    public interface IListPickerPage
    {
        string HeaderText { get; set; }
        IList Items { get; }
        SelectionMode SelectionMode { get; set; }
        object SelectedItem { get; set; }
        IList SelectedItems { get; }
        DataTemplate FullModeItemTemplate { get; set; }
        bool IsOpen { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then, when you want to use it, you just specify your own page instead, by setting the `PickerPageUri`

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lpStr"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Width="1"
                                    Height="1"
                                    CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                                    ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"
                                    Foreground="Black"
                                    FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerStringLargeTemplate}"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    Opacity="0"
                                    PickerPageUri="/Views/Globals/ToolkitPages/MyListPickerPage.xaml" />
            </Grid>
```

The rest is simply customizing your own `ListPickerPage xaml` file to fit your requirements.

Comment: How will this change the background color of the Popup window? I only see references to Foreground?

Comment: You have to take the XAML file from the source code of the toolkit, and modify it as you'd like. THen you refer to it using PickerPageUri. I purposefully didn't put it here b/c it would be outdated in the future